# SQL SELECT only rows having MAX value of a column from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

My two table setup is like below:

table1

```
+------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | tail    | content                              |
+------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | abc     | ...                                  |
| 2    | def     | ...                                  |
| 3    | ghi     | ...                                  |
| 4    | def     | ...                                  |
| 5    | jkl     | ...                                  |
+------+-------+----------------------------------------+
```

table2

```
+------+--------+---------------------------------------+
| id   | tailID | value   |  others                     |
+------+--------+---------------------------------------+
| 1    | 2      | 412     |                             |
| 2    | 3      | 215     |                             |
| 1    | 2      | 571     |                             |
| 1    | 4      | 123     |                             |
+------+--------+---------------------------------------+
```

I like to get all columns from this two tables in a row with matched tail = tailID but not duplicate rows which has same tail.

For the duplicate TAIL, just need to get the single row of max VALUE of same tail.

I am currently using

```
SELECT table1.tail, table2.other_column 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 
on table1.id = table2.tailID 
WHERE table1.some_coloum = "a sepecific string" 
ORDER BY table2.value
```

But it returns many duplicates of same tail.

I just need to have single row for duplicate TAIL with hightes VALUE of table2.

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: And while editing the question, add the expected result too.

Comment: Have you tried to run any code?

Comment: Question corrected.

Comment: @gofr1 My question is based on mysql. Your answer works perfect for my query, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BishawjitDas my pleasure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT with CROSS APPLY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.tail,
                t2.other_column,
                t3.[value]
FROM table1 t1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  tailid,
            MAX([value]) as [value]
    FROM table2
    WHERE tailid = t1.id
    GROUP BY tailid
    ) as t3
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t2.tailid = t3.tailid AND t3.[value] = t2.[value]
WHERE t1.some_coloum = "a sepecific string"
```

Comment: This is wrong. As you don't specify an aggregate function for `t2.other_column` the DBMS will pick them arbitrarily. To pick the correct ones you would need a function to get the `t2.other_column` where `value` is the maximum for the group. Such function (like Oracle's KEEP FIRST/LAST) doesn't exist in MySQL. So you need a different approach. For example the one shown by Serg.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It is for SQL Server, this question was tagged with this tag by OP. I ask question about RDBMS used to OP. If SQL Server was tagged mistakenly - I will remove my answer.

Comment: Ah, okay. And I didn't even see that `t2.other_column` is in `GROUP BY`. So of course it doesn't get arbitrarily picked, neither in MySQL nor in SQL Server. It doesn't work though, because it gives you the max `value` per `other_column` where you actually want it vice versa.

Comment: That makes sense, changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First group table2 then join

```
SELECT table1.tail, table2.other_column 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT tailID, max(value) as value
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY tailID
) t2g ON t2g.tailID = table1.ID
INNER JOIN table2 
on t2g.tailID = table2.tailID AND  t2g.value = table2.value
WHERE table1.some_coloum = "a sepecific string" 
ORDER BY table2.value
```

The query still may return multiple rows for a `table1` row if there are 2 or more rows in `table2` with the same `max(value)` and `tailID`.

Answer (score 0):

Selected only rows where is MAX value of column `value`

```
SELECT table1.tail, MAX(table2.value)
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.tailID
  WHERE table1.content = "test"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b70d29/3/0